# Stop propagation: bubble down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, stoppropagation

Im not sure this is a propagation issue as much as a design flaw and I have read that propagation issues are all ways a bubble up but here it goes. I have a table edit grid.

Each cell contains two main blocks: Editing div(contains a form to edit the displayed value) & view div(contains display values). All overflow hidden in order to make every row of same height.

On load Editing div is not displayed and view div is. On hover of cell editing div is shown and view values are not.

On phones/tablets hover doesn't kick in so click is required on cell to swop from view to edit and other way around.

The problem comes when the editing view contains clickable elements(in this case tags). On phones/tablets if click is done on coordinates where those clickable elements will appear those elements will be clicked.

```
<td  class="editGridCell" ng-if="!block && ($index > 0)" ng-repeat="attobj in columns track by $index">
  <div class="contentEdit">    
    <form name="theForm" novalidate>
      <div ng-if="true"  ng-init="attobj = attobj.attobj" ng-include src="getAttValuesEditorTemplate(dbo, attobj)">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-class="compressed ? 'contentValues' : 'contentValuesDecompressed'">
    <div  ng-repeat="v in dbo.get4(attobj.key) track by $index">
      <p ng-if="v.cid">{{ v.displayName() }}</p>
      <p ng-if="!v.cid">{{ v }}</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</td>
```

Template the form calls containing tags that are clickable:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_ref">
  <div ng-init="tmp = dbo.get(attobj.name)">
    <div ng-model="tmp" ui-sortable="{ 'ui-floating': undefined}" class="clearfix">
      <div ng-repeat="dbo2 in dbo.get(attobj.name) track by $index" style="float:left; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="tag sortableTag">
          <a href="#/view/{{ dbo2.cid }}" target="_blank">{{ dbo2.displayName() }}</a>
          <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeValue(dbo, attobj.name, $index)"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-include="'typeaheadtemplate'" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</script>
```

css:

```
.superResponsive .editGridCell{
  border: 1px solid lightBlue;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.contentEdit{
  display:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:4px;

}

.contentValues{
  display:block;
  color:#0887A7!important;
  min-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*min-width:100px;*/
  width:100%;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.contentValuesDecompressed{
  display:block;
  color:#0887A7!important;
  min-height: 25px;
  overflow: visible;
  /*min-width:100px;*/
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contentDecompressed{
    color:#0887A7!important;
    min-height: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

.editGridCell:hover .contentEdit{
  display: block;
  height:auto;
  width: 90%;
  background:#d8ecf2;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  overflow: visible;
}

.editGridCell:hover .contentValuesDecompressed{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.editGridCell:hover .contentValues{
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

ON PHONES I CLICK ON CELL & TAG IS CLICKED(IF TAG WILL SHOW)!
[image]

Simplified issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/yqjzvcyw/

Comment: We can't troubleshoot your image. There is nothing in code shown relating to click handling. Provide the relevant code. A demo that replicates problem would also help

Comment: Added, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can delay the hover effect like:

html:

```
<div class="aDiv">
    <a class="aLink" href="https://google.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.aDiv{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
}
.aLink{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.aDiv:hover .aLink{
    visibility:visible;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/yqjzvcyw/12/